# SQLITE JOIN tables on composite primary key

Tags: sqlite, join, composite-primary-key

Using SQLlite in a TCL script I have three tables:

```
            DB eval { CREATE TABLE CompFIs       ( EID int NOT NULL , PlyID  int NOT NULL  , LC int NOT NULL , FI float NOT NULL , SR float   , ImagePath text ,   PRIMARY KEY ( LC, EID, PlyID )) }
            DB eval { CREATE TABLE CompStresses  ( EID int NOT NULL , PlyID  int NOT NULL  , LC int NOT NULL , sigx float        , sigy float , sigxy float    ,   PRIMARY KEY ( LC, EID, PlyID )) }
            DB eval { CREATE TABLE ElemMetadata  ( EID int NOT NULL , AssyID int NOT NULL ,  PID int  ,  PRIMARY KEY ( EID )) }
```

I now want to know the Maximum FI from the first table 'CompFIs' for a given AssID.
For that FI (Failure Index) i need the corresponding values from the other tables. 
In order to achive this I thougt I join the tables using the Primary Keys.

I do however not find how to join tables using their PK.
Instead I tried the following:

```
SELECT
ElemMetadata.EID     AS EID      ,
ElemMetadata.AssyID  AS AssyID   ,
ElemMetadata.PID     AS PID      ,
CompFIs.PlyID        AS Ply      ,
CompFIs.LC           AS LC       ,
CompFIs.FI           AS FI       ,
CompFIs.SR           AS SR       ,
CompStresses.sigx    AS sigx     ,
CompStresses.sigy    AS sigy     ,
CompStresses.sigxy   AS sigxy
FROM
CompFIs 
LEFT JOIN CompStresses ON CompFIs.EID = CompStresses.EID
LEFT JOIN ElemMetadata ON CompFIs.EID = ElemMetadata.EID
WHERE AssyID = 1 ORDER BY  FI DESC LIMIT 5
```

This does not work because the data is only matched using the EID columns.

How can I join tables based on their Composite PKs ?

Example Values:

```
Table: CompFIs
--------------------------------------------------
EID     PlyID   LC      FI      SR      ImagePath 
--------------------------------------------------
282812  7       1       1.2824  null    null 
282813  2       3       0.3333  null    null

Table: ElemMetadata
--------------------------------------------------
EID     AssyID  PID
--------------------------------------------------
282812  1       51
282813  1       51

Table: CompStresses
--------------------------------------------------
EID     PlyID   LC      sigx    sigy    sigxy
--------------------------------------------------
282812  1       1       30.7    169.9   -31.13
282813  1       1       12.7    180.7   55.2


Expected output:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EID     AssyID  PID     Ply     LC      FI      SR      sigx    sigy    sigxy
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
282812  1       51      1       1       1.2824  null    30.7    169.9   -31.13
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Same way you'd join any tables on multiple conditions... `... FROM foo JOIN bar ON foo.x = bar.x AND foo.y = bar.y AND foo.z = bar.z`. Your tables don't have rows with the same PK values in common though so I don't see how you get those particular results.

Comment: PKs & other constraints are not needed to query. They just make more expressions return the same answer that otherwise wouldn't. What matters is what a row in a base table or query result means. "based on their Composite PKs" doesn't tell us anything. When giving a relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`CTE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) and `NOT EXISTS`:

```
with cte as (
  SELECT
  ElemMetadata.EID     AS EID      ,
  ElemMetadata.AssyID  AS AssyID   ,
  ElemMetadata.PID     AS PID      ,
  CompFIs.PlyID        AS Ply      ,
  CompFIs.LC           AS LC       ,
  CompFIs.FI           AS FI       ,
  CompFIs.SR           AS SR       ,
  CompStresses.sigx    AS sigx     ,
  CompStresses.sigy    AS sigy     ,
  CompStresses.sigxy   AS sigxy
  FROM
  CompFIs 
  LEFT JOIN CompStresses ON CompFIs.EID = CompStresses.EID
  LEFT JOIN ElemMetadata ON CompFIs.EID = ElemMetadata.EID 
  WHERE AssyID = 1 
  ORDER BY  FI DESC LIMIT 5
) 

select c.* from cte c 
where not exists (
  select 1 from cte
  where FI > c.FI
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bVsxG7ojfcuthymd7YKyZx/2).
Results:

```
| EID    | AssyID | PID | Ply | LC  | FI     | SR  | sigx | sigy  | sigxy  |
| ------ | ------ | --- | --- | --- | ------ | --- | ---- | ----- | ------ |
| 282812 | 1      | 51  | 7   | 1   | 1.2824 |     | 30.7 | 169.9 | -31.13 |
```

Comment: Ok, I thought there is a way using the PK directly. I do however get  NULL for sigx sigy sigxy. When looking upp sigy sigy sigxy in table CompStresses there are values for the given EID LC and PlyID combination.

Comment: If there was a match for all 3 columns you would get the matching row for sure. So check again. Do a `SELECT * ...` instead to check for CompStresses.EID, CompStresses.LC, CompStresses.PlyID. If they are null then there is no match.

Comment: I did. The problem as I understand it is, that the table CompStresses does not have a column AssyID. So the WHERE AssyID=1 does not generate a match in table CompStresses.

Comment: Remove the WHERE clause and put the condition in the ON clause. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Unfortunally it still does not work. I added example values to the question, maybe it helps in finding a solution.

Comment: You don't have matching all 3 columns in both tables. Why did you want to join on all 3 of them?